# Python bc_dict, TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I'm attempting to demultiplex DNA reads that were prepared using a novel sequencing approach. The Python script designed to complete this task is throwing an error that I'm unsure of how to resolve:

```
 File "demultiplex3.1.py", line 693, in <module>
    bc_dict = parse_bc(opts.barcode, Flowcell, Lane)
  File "demultiplex3.1.py", line 315, in parse_bc
    bc_dict[bc_instance.get_seq()] = bc_instance
  File "demultiplex3.1.py", line 266, in get_seq
    R1_start = (self.Wobble_R1, self.Barcode_R1 + 'Y' + self.enz_remnant_R1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

I have tried to run this using PyCharm 2016.1.4 as well as on my university's research computing cluster and have received the same error on both platforms.

Here are the lines of code where the errors are originating:

Lines 693-697

```py
bc_dict = parse_bc(opts.barcode, Flowcell, Lane)
if not os.path.exists(opts.outputdir):
    os.mkdir(opts.outputdir)
opts.output = tempfile.mkdtemp(prefix='seq', dir=opts.outputdir)
if os.path.exists(opts.output):
```

Lines 314-316

```py
if bc_instance.Flowcell == fc and bc_instance.Lane == ln:
bc_dict[bc_instance.get_seq()] = bc_instance
    return bc_dict
```

Lines 262-269

```py
    def get_seq(self):
        """Return sequence to search on left and right read"""
        # design of Read_1 is NNN|BARCODE|CONTROL-NT|ENZ-REMNANT
        # CONTROL-NT for R1  is either C or T, put Y as control nucleotide
        R1_start = (self.Wobble_R1, self.Barcode_R1 + 'Y' + self.enz_remnant_R1)
        # CONTROL-NT for R2  is either G or A, put R as control nucleotide
        R2_start = (self.Wobble_R2, self.Barcode_R2 + 'Y' + self.enz_remnant_R2)
        return (R1_start, R2_start)
```

I'm not the author of the code and am rather green when it comes to resolving errors in Python coding. The demultiplexing script is designed to attach sample names to the fragments based on the barcoded adapters that were attached during the laboratory preparation of the samples and then strip the barcoded adapter sequences so that just the sample tag and the fragments remain in the fastq files.

Answer (score 1):

```
R1_start = (self.Wobble_R1, self.Barcode_R1 + 'Y' + self.enz_remnant_R1)
```

The error

> unsupported operand type(s) for `+`: `NoneType` and `str`"

means that the code's trying to do `A + B` where `A` is None and `B` is a string, an illegal operation. It can't be second `+` since its left operand (the result of `self.Barcode_R1 + 'Y'`) is clearly not None. It must be the left `+`.

Hence, `self.Barcode_R1` must be None. You'll need to backtrack and figure out what that variable is and where it gets its value.

Comment: If you anticipate the possibilities where there may be a realistic `None` value for `self.enz_remnant_R1` often, you could use `str(self.enz_remnant_R1)` to get a value of `'None'` concatenated to the end.